# Google Maps API extract elevation value along route

Tags: javascript, google-maps, web-mapping, google-maps-api, google-maps-api-3

I am using the Directions and Elevation Service of Google Maps, in order to extract the coordinates and the elevation along a route between a start and end point. I could set my directions service successfully, I could also extract the elevation values. Everything works fine at the first request, but if I send a second request I got the error message:

"InvalidValueError: in property path: fewer than 2 LatLngs".

[image: screenshot of error message]

I also noticed, that if I reload my page in Firefox, the error disappears. But if I don't reload my webpage, the error remains.

Below you can see my code:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
 var directionsDisplay;
 directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
 var map;
});

$(window).on('load', function () {
 initMap();
});

 function initMap() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.7758459, 9.1829321),
    mapTypeControl: false

}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

}

//take start and end from input field
function calcRoute() {

var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
var end =  document.getElementById("end").value;

//send request to server
var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
};

path = [];

//get result from google maps server as response
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

        pointsArray = response.routes[0].overview_path;

        var i = 0;
        var j = 0;

        //get long lat of vertices along route
        for (j = 0; j < pointsArray.length; j++) {
            lat = pointsArray[j].lat();
            lng = pointsArray[j].lng();

            //save lat long in path array
            path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));

        //create marker
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
            map: map    
            }); 
        }   

    }
});

//Create an ElevationService
var elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService;
displayPathElevation(path, elevator, map);

function displayPathElevation(path, elevator, map) {

new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: path,
    strokeColor: '#0000CC',
    strokeOpacity: 0.4,
    map: map
});

elevator.getElevationAlongPath({
    'path': path,
    'samples': 256
}, plotElevation);

}

function plotElevation(elevations, status) {
 if (status === 'OK') {
    for (var i=0; i < elevations.length; i++) {
        console.log(elevations[i].location.lat() );
        console.log(elevations[i].location.lng() );
        console.log(elevations[i].elevation);
     }
  }


};
```

Here are my libs and buttons:

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <label for="Start">Start</label><input id="start" type="textbox"></input><br/>
    <label for="End">End</label><input id="end" type="textbox"></input><br/><br/>
    <input id="submit" type="button" class="btn btn-dark" value="search" onclick="calcRoute();"><br/><br/>
    <div id="chart"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="map"></div>
 <script defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api  /js?key=MY_API_KEY=initMap"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a timeout on the displayPathElevation function.

setTimeout(function() {
                    displayPathElevation(path, elevator, map);
                }, 500);

Answer (score 0):

The directions service is asynchronous.  Use the path returned in the callback function when/where it exists.

(You can also simplify your code to remove the code that creates new `google.maps.LatLng` object, just use the ones returned by the directions service)

```
//get result from google maps server as response
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

        pointsArray = response.routes[0].overview_path;

        //get long lat of vertices along route
        for (j = 0; j < pointsArray.length; j++) {
        //create marker
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pointsArray[j],
            map: map    
            }); 
        }   
    }
    //Create an ElevationService
    var elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService;
    displayPathElevation(path, elevator, map);
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/wy8srgn2/3/)

[image: screenshot with one route]

[image: screenshot with second route]